# Quickly Switch Documentation

Tags: application-development

Does anyone know where I can find documentation on the Switch Widget on glade??

I tried finding on the GTK website, but it doesn't have an entry for it.

**EDIT**

Thank you to Timo for pointing me in the right direction. I am loving askubuntu!.

Basically my problem was that the connect function by defualts pushes the Window's Object, The Widget's Object and the Active State to whichever function you run on the callback.

***This is the before:***

```py
self.daymon.connect("notify::active", self.toggle_day("mon"))
```

***And this is the after:***

```py
self.daymon.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "mon")
```

The latter works like a charm when running the following function:

```py
def toggle_day(self, widget, active, day):  
    if widget.get_active():  
        state = True  
    else:  
        state = False
```

***Full code to follow should you be interested:***

```py
# -*- Mode: Python; coding: utf-8; indent-tabs-mode: nil; tab-width: 4 -*-
### BEGIN LICENSE
# This file is in the public domain
### END LICENSE

import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('snooze')

from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('snooze')

import ConfigParser, os # We need to be able to store and recal settings

from snooze_lib import Window
from snooze.AboutSnoozeDialog import AboutSnoozeDialog
from snooze.PreferencesSnoozeDialog import PreferencesSnoozeDialog

#first try to read the config.cfg file
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configFile = 'data/config.cfg'
monState = False
tueState = False
wedState = False
thurState = False
friState = False
satState = False
sunState = False

# Creating the Config file
def createConfigFile(fileName):
    print "CREATING CONFIG"
    config.add_section('Preferences')
    config.set('Preferences', 'mon', False)
    config.set('Preferences', 'tues', False)
    config.set('Preferences', 'wed', False)
    config.set('Preferences', 'thur', False)
    config.set('Preferences', 'fri', False)
    config.set('Preferences', 'sat', False)
    config.set('Preferences', 'sun', False)
    rewriteConfigFile(filename)

# Writing our configuration file to the failename as specifeid
def rewriteConfigFile(filename):    
    with open(filename, 'wb') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

# Reading the config file 
def readConfigFile(fileName):
    print "READING CONFIG"
    global monState, tueState, wedState, thurState, friState, satState, sunState
    monState = config.getboolean('Preferences', 'mon')
    tueState = config.getboolean('Preferences', 'tues')
    wedState = config.getboolean('Preferences', 'wed')
    thurState = config.getboolean('Preferences', 'thur')
    friState = config.getboolean('Preferences', 'fri')
    satState = config.getboolean('Preferences', 'sat')
    sunState = config.getboolean('Preferences', 'sun')

# If the config does not exist, create it then read it. Otherwise read it
if not config.read(configFile):    
    createConfigFile(configFile)
    readConfigFile(configFile)    
else:
    readConfigFile(configFile)

# See snooze_lib.Window.py for more details about how this class works
class SnoozeWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "SnoozeWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(SnoozeWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        self.AboutDialog = AboutSnoozeDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesSnoozeDialog

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
        self.daymon = self.builder.get_object("daymon")
        self.daytues = self.builder.get_object("daytues")
        self.daywed = self.builder.get_object("daywed")
        self.daythur = self.builder.get_object("daythur")
        self.dayfri = self.builder.get_object("dayfri")
        self.daysat = self.builder.get_object("daysat")
        self.daysun = self.builder.get_object("daysun")

        # Set the values based on the config file        
        if monState == True:
            self.daymon.activate()

        if tueState == True:
            self.daytues.activate()

        if wedState == True:
            self.daywed.activate()

        if thurState == True:
            self.daythur.activate()

        if friState == True:
            self.dayfri.activate()

        if satState == True:
            self.daysat.activate()

        if sunState == True:
           self.daysun.activate()

        self.daymon.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "mon")
        self.daytues.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "tues")
        self.daywed.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "wed")
        self.daythur.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "thur")
        self.dayfri.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "fri")
        self.daysat.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "sat")
        self.daysun.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "sun")

    # Toggle the setting and store the information in the config file
    def toggle_day(self, widget, active, day):
        if widget.get_active():
            state = True
        else:
            state = False

        # Set the config option and update the config file
        global configFile
        config.set('Preferences', day, state)
        rewriteConfigFile(configFile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSwitch.html

Complete reference with all widgets and more useful info: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/

The GtkSwitch has only one signal, [`activate`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSwitch.html#GtkSwitch-activate). You shouldn't directly connect to it according to the docs:

> Applications should never connect to this signal, but use the
>   notify::active signal.

So connecting should be as simple as:

```
switch.connect('notify::active', _switch_active_changed_cb)
```

The `notify::foo` principle can be used on any widget, it actually listens on property changes.

Read more about connecting signals in the [documentation](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#main-loop-and-signals).

Comment: Thank you Timo, do you possibly know how the event binding works on these? Can't seem to find quickly specific examples

Comment: These aren't Quickly specific questions, just regular PyGTK (or PyGI nowadays). I'll update my answer a bit, which should look and read better than a comment.

Comment: Timo you rock, but seems my PHP brain can't connect the dots.

I am using the following in order to reference the button:
`self.daymon = self.builder.get_object("daymon")`

But how would I reference the action in relation to it?
`self.daymon.connect("notify::active", self.toggle_day("mon"))`

Is this the right way to connect the event to a function?

Comment: Ermagerd, think I found my issue:  
`self.daymon.connect('notify::active', self.toggle_day, "mon")`  
  
The connect function takes the data as an additional parameter, that's if I am not crazy.

Comment: You're right! And your callback function should have following signature: `def toggle_day(self, widget, active, user_data)`

Comment: Whoops, you already found that out in your answer! Little simplification: `widget.get_active()` returns a bool, so you can just do `state = widget.get_active()` and forget about the if...else.

Comment: C-c-c-combo comment! There's even more redundant code as I look at it. Many things could be simplified. If you're interested, I'll take a closer look it to do some rewrites.

Comment: LOL, thank you Timo. Hey I am no Pro, it works so for the time being I am happy with it.

Any help would be appreaciated.